# Post base64 to Amazon API Gateway

Tags: api, http, amazon-web-services, base64, aws-api-gateway

I've been searching a lot on this topic but no luck.
My API accepts a base64 string as a payload of a POST request. The base64 is the representation of an image. I use Amazon API gateway as a proxy. I've created a POST /uploadImage64 method in the resources tree, choosing HTTP as integration type.
In the "Method Request" block, API gateway allows me specifying only a JSON model in the "Request Body" section, but my payload is not application/json . Hence, the exported SDK does not allow posting any base64 payload.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks!
Roberto

Comment: I temporarily solved subclassing the AWS API Gateway client in the Amazon SDK generated from the portal, and overriding the methods I need, by adding the body paramer. Please tell me if you have a better solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the Models only support JSON so the generated SDK would have to either be something like { 'payload' -> base64 } or as Roberto suggested, extending the SDK yourself.

There really isn't a 'model' for base64 data that can be represented as a native object anyway, so I think generically extending or looking deeper in the SDK for the spot where you can just pass a string payload is what you want.